# OpenCV capture from raspberry pi camera

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.0

How would I go about capturing an image for use in OpenCV from the standard camera module v2 plugged into a Raspberry Pi 3B? I've been trying to get high frame-rate video working, but using OpenCV's `VideoCapture` always gives me an empty `Mat` when I try to index device `0`, and [this](https://github.com/Hopding/JRPiCam) and [this](https://github.com/caprica/picam) both produced 1 frame per second or worse when I tried. I've also looked into spawning a `raspivid` process, but I don't see a way to get OpenCV's `VideoCapture` to read from the output of that process.

How would I get high FPS frame capture in Java? Is there a way I can get OpenCV to read from an `OutputStream` that I grab from another process?

*EDIT*: a simplified version of my code is below. I want to know how to populate the `startRecording()` function in this class

```
abstract class Main {
    public static Mat currentCapture = null;
    public static final double FOV_HEIGHT = 48.8;
    public static final int WIDTH = 480;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 384;
    public static final int VIDEO_WIDTH = WIDTH * 2;
    public static final int VIDEO_HEIGHT = HEIGHT * 2;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(org.opencv.core.Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        client = new VisionClientTable("10.55.6.4", 5506);
        new Thread(new VisionThread(VisionThread.Mode.VIDEO)).start();
        new Thread(new VisionThread(VisionThread.Mode.TARGETING)).start();
    }

    private static class VisionThread implements Runnable {
        private final Mode mode;

        enum Mode {
            VIDEO,
            TARGETING
        }

        public VisionThread(Mode mode) {
            this.mode = mode;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mode == Mode.TARGETING)
                startTracking();
            else if (mode == Mode.VIDEO)
                startRecording();
        }
    }

    public static void startTracking() {
        /* this thread repeatedly captures currentCapture and processes it */
    }

    // this is where I need help
    public static void startRecording() {
        try {
            VideoWriter video = new VideoWriter("/home/pi/vision/videos/video-" + Files.list(Paths.get("/home/pi/vision/captures")).count() + ".mp4", VideoWriter.fourcc('X', '2', '6', '4'), 30, new Size(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT), true);
            VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
            capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, VIDEO_WIDTH);
            capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            while (true) {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Mat mat = new Mat();
                capture.read(mat);
                if (!mat.empty()) { // mat is always empty
                    Mat downscaled = new Mat();
                    Imgproc.resize(mat, downscaled, new Size(WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_NEAREST);
                    currentCapture = downscaled;
                }
                video.write(mat);
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (end - start < 1000 / 60)
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / 60 - (end - start));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void log(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

I feel like the best way to do this might be to set `raspivid` to output to a file, and somehow feed the output of it into OpenCV, but I'm not sure how to do this.

*EDIT 2*: So far, I have tried using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run a `raspivid` command that outputs to a file, which works, but then when I try to open that file with OpenCV, `capture.isOpened()` remains false, even as the program repeatedly tries to open the file.

Comment: could you please share your code.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

not getting much idea about your code from your question.
following may help you.

http://bigdinotech.com/tutorials/beaglebone-black-tutorials/building-opencv-on-the-beaglebone-black-or-raspberry-pi/